# Alternative for org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow in eclipse 4.x

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am migrating eclipse IDE product from 362 to 422. I have the below line of code which throws cast cast exception as WorkbenchWindow is no longer derived from ApplicationWindow for eclipse 4.x.

ICoolBarManager coolBarMgr = ((ApplicationWindow) window).getCoolBarManager();

Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow

As a workaround, I can use below lines for rcp app which extends org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.

ICoolBarManager coolBarMgr = getWindowConfigurer().getActionBarConfigurer().getCoolBarManager();

But I have to use eclipse IDE (not rcp) where it does not have any plugin that extends org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor, so above workaround does not help me.

Could you please provide any suggestion on alternate solution to get ICoolBarManager without using getWindowConfigurer() without lot of code changes?
OR is there any way so that I can use getWindowConfigurer() from another plugin that does not extend org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WorkbenchWindow` has a `getCoolBarManager2` method **but** `WorkbenchWindow` is an internal class so this really should not be used (nor should your original method). I dpn't think there is an official method of accessing the `ICoolBarManager`.

Note Eclipse 4.2.2 is pretty old now, there have been a lot of fixes to Eclipse 4 since then.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative. This actually works but the method use is discouraged. May I know what are the consequences of using discouraged method or class? Also, any alternative if you suggest that will be helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Internal classes may change at any time, any release might break your code. Your original method was also breaking the rules because the fact that the workbench window extended `ApplicationWindow` was an implementation detail you should not have relied on. See [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for valuable comment.